Selenium throws "NoSuchElementException" while using Google search
It should search from Google, but I open and close Google and then I get an error like this.
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
 Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
 {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*  
[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/a/h3"}
(Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.86); For documentation on this 
error, please visit:'

Here are the codes I wrote.
elif "google aç" in gelen_ses or "arama yap" in gelen_ses:
self.seslendirme("Ne açmamı istersiniz efendim?")
veri=self.ses_kayit()
self.seslendirme("Bulduklarımı size sunmak için açıyorum efendim.".format(veri))
url="https://www.google.com/search?q={}".format(veri)
tarayici=webdriver.Chrome()
tarayici.get(url)
buton=tarayici.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/a/h3').click()

I was waiting for her to open Google, search what I said and click on the first one that comes up, but she opens Google and closes it without even searching.

Where did you get that XPATH?  Have you actually verified that there is such an element in that page?  Have you looked at the DOM?

search engines often change their html structure and xpaths have only a short lifetime

It's unclear which h3 element you're trying to access. You may find using a CSS selector more effective.
Here's a runnable snippet (providing you have selenium installed) that will reveal all h3 elements:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

OPTIONS = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
OPTIONS.add_argument("--headless=true")

QUERY = "What is the population of Cape Town, South Africa"
URL = f"https://www.google.com/search?q='{QUERY}'"

def text(e: WebElement) -> str | bool | dict | WebElement:
    return e.text or e.get_property("textContent") or "n/a"

def main():
    with webdriver.Chrome(OPTIONS) as driver:
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.get(URL)
        for h3 in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3"):
            print(text(h3))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
Cape Town
Cape Town | History, Population, Map, Climate, & Facts
Cape Town, South Africa Population 2024
Cape Town, South Africa Metro Area Population 1950-2024
City of Cape Town
Cape Town
Total population of South Africa 2023, by province
Metropolitan Municipality - Cape Town
Your Expat Cape Town Information Guide | Basic Facts
Cape Town | Global Future Cities Programme
Description

